# Loop through shapes and do IncrementLeft

Tags: excel, vba

I need to reposition my shapes because all are in one place. Shapes have pictures in it and I want to do `IncrementLeft` starting from the shape with name 2 then go to 3 and last. Next shape has to `IncrementLeft` from the previous shape, not the first one so I have all shapes in a row and in the same distance.

Here is part of my code, which moves all shapes according to shape 1:

```
For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If shp.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRectangle Then
        If shp.Name > "1" Then
           shp.IncrementLeft 146
        End If
    End If
Next shp
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `New position of shape = Left of old shape + Width of old shape + Margin space`

Comment: Which is the last shape number or is it dynamic? also do you want the shapes to be in increasing order.. in the sense, 1,2,3,4,5 or any order will do?

Comment: number of shapes are dynamic from 1 to last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shp.IncrementLeft 146` is a bad idea. If the shape's width gets resized then it may cause undesired results.

Further to my comments below your question,

```
New position of shape = Left of old shape + Width of old shape + Margin space
```

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lstShp As Integer
    Dim shpLft As Double, shpTop As Double, shpWidth As Double
    Dim inBetweenMargin As Double
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> In betwen margin
    inBetweenMargin = 25 '~~> 146????

    '~~> Set this to the respective sheet
    Set ws = Sheet2

    With ws
        '~~> Get the max shape number(name)
        For Each shp In .Shapes
            If shp.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRectangle Then
                If Val(shp.Name) > 1 And Val(shp.Name) > lstShp Then _
                lstShp = Val(shp.Name)
            End If
        Next

        '~~> Loop through the shapes
        For i = 1 To lstShp
            '~~> This is required in case you delete shape 3
            '~~> and have only shapes 1,2,4,5 etc...
            On Error Resume Next
            Set shp = .Shapes(Cstr(i))
            On Error GoTo 0

            '~~> position them
            If Not shp Is Nothing Then
                If shpLft = 0 And shpTop = 0 And shpWidth = 0 Then
                    shpLft = shp.Left
                    shpTop = shp.Top
                    shpWidth = shp.Width
                Else
                    shp.Top = shpTop
                    shp.Left = shpLft + shpWidth + inBetweenMargin

                    shpLft = shp.Left
                    shpWidth = shp.Width
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: I try your code but everything is moving slicers, command buttons but no rectangle shapes? What i do wrong?

Comment: Try this.. Change the line in my code `If Not shp Is Nothing Then` to `If Not shp Is Nothing and shp.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRectangle Then`

Comment: Are you sure the shapes are `msoShapeRectangle` and they have numeric names?

Comment: Can i See your file? If yes then you can upload it on www.wikisend.com and share the link here

Comment: Sorry, but i cant share the file because it contains all company data. All my pictures are in msorectangle shape and the name of each shape comes from loop for i = 1 to lastrow. Maybe here is a problem? I dont know if the loop numbers are integers or string or text.

Comment: Can you copy couple of shapes to a blank excel file and share that?

Comment: @SiddharthRout note that `shp = .Shapes(i)` is moving the shape with **index** `i` but that is not necessarily the shape with the **name** `i` therefore it should be `shp = .Shapes(CStr(i))` I think?

Comment: shp = .Shapes(CStr(i)) solves it and now its moving only pictures

Comment: @Tomz" Try what Peh suggested. Change `Set shp = .Shapes(i)` to `Set shp = .Shapes(CStr(i))`

Comment: Thank you both for your help. Propably later i will have another problem because i have to add another restriction to positioning photos. When more than 6 in row than start placing another photos below the 1 photo. I will try to make it myself but if i will stuck with the code i can reply here or make new question?

Comment: @Tomz Better ask a new question showing what you have tried.

Comment: It is pretty easy @Tomz `New .Top = Old  shape Top + Old Shp Height + Margin` ;) Give it a try. If you get stuck then like Pᴇʜ suggested ask a new question showing what you have tried :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I believe that your `Double` should all be `Single` to avoid unnecessary type castings.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout just a little question, how to define the first shape with number 1 and get position below him with shape number 7? Trying to adapt your code with old shape top etc. I should declare first shape somehow?

Comment: @Tomz: `Set Shp = ws.Shapes("1")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the position of the previous `shp` as origin for the next one.

Try something like this:

```
Dim Origin As Single

Dim shp As Shape
For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If shp.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRectangle Then
        If Val(shp.Name) > 1 Then
           shp.IncrementLeft Origin + 146
           Origin = shp.Left 'depending on what you want it might be shp.Left + shp.Width here
        End If
    End If
Next shp
```